# Create an automation Wait activity via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, automationstudio

Is it possible to create a wait activity step in an automation via preferably SOAP API or I know there is an undocumented REST API. Could a single wait activity be used on multiple automations?

Comment: Hi, have you been able to find a solution to this in the meantime? I'm facing the same challenge right now

Comment: No, I did not find a solution unfortunately. Will update this question if I ever do.

Answer (score 1):

So I found this by observing the network tab in the developer console when you create an automation with a wait activity and save it.
You can post a JSON to `YOUR_REST_ENDPOINT/automation/v1/automations` and it will create an automation with a wait activity:

```
POST /automation/v1/automations
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "SSJS_API_Test",
  "key": "SSJS_API_Test_Key",
  "steps": [ 
    {
      "annotation":"",
      "stepNumber":0,
      "activities": [
        {
          "name":"10 Minutes",
          "objectTypeId":467,
          "displayOrder":0,
          "activityObjectId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "serializedObject":"{\"duration\":10,\"durationUnits\":\"Minutes\"}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "startSource": {
    "typeId":1
  },
  "categoryId":544
}
```

To update an existing automation, I think you'd have to use the `PATCH` method instead of `POST`.